# How do I identify if my certificate contains private key?

Tags: ssl, certificate

According to [the answer to this server-fault question](https://serverfault.com/questions/9708/what-is-a-pem-file-and-how-does-it-differ-from-other-openssl-generated-key-file)  almost all certificate file formats can contain private key alongside public key, as such how can I identify whether a certificate contains private key?

This is important because I do not want to unknowingly send the private key to the remote client.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Following the structure of the link:

- **.csr**. Only public keys in `pem` or `der` format
- **.pem**. keys and/or certificates. Look for `-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY----` or `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----` or `-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----`
- **.key** keys in `pem` format
- **.pkcs12 .pfx .p12** keys and/or certificates. List keys with `openssl pkcs12 -info -nocerts -in keystore.p12`
- **.jks** keys and/or certificates. Java specific format.
- **.der** `pem` content without base64 encoding. Look for `KEY` in `openssl x509   -inform DER -in cert.der`
- **.cert .cer .crt** keys and/or certificates. Content can be `pem` or `der`
- **.p7b**. Only certificates
- **.crl**. No keys

Comment: Hmm, a .CSR will contain your public key. After all, its whole purpose is to request that the public key be signed.

Comment: csr must contain the public key

Comment: @ferg, @JunchenLiu, `keys` refers to private keys in the answer. I have modified it to eliminate ambiguity.