# Setting Up HTTPS in Express JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, https

I bought an AlphaSSL from a hosting provider. They just gave me

- domain.csr.crt
- domain.interCert.crt
- domain.PKCS7Cert.crt
- domain.rootCert.crt
- domain.X509Cert.crt

But as I know that to run HTTPS on Node.JS using Express, I need at least key file and cert file. Then, what kind of file I should use? Thank you.

Comment: Did you have key file?

Comment: @TienDuong No I didn't. The hosting provider just give me those cert file.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a private key and a certificate file, here's a simple example of an HTTPS server in Node.js, you can see we need to load both the private key and certificate files. If you have a .pfx file this may contain both the certificate *and* the private key. Check this question out as well, you may have the private key in one of the .crt files: [How do I identify if my certificate contains private key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41460230/how-do-i-identify-if-my-certificate-contains-private-key)

**Example using private key and cert:**

```
const fs = require('fs');
const https = require('https');
const privateKey  = fs.readFileSync('./privateKey.key', 'utf8');
const certificate = fs.readFileSync('./certificate.crt', 'utf8');

const credentials = { key: privateKey, cert: certificate };
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

// Add test route here. 
app.get("/test", (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).send("All good");
})

const server = https.createServer(credentials, app);
server.listen(8443);
```

**Using .pfx file:**

```
const https = require('https');
const fs = require('fs');

const options = {
  pfx: fs.readFileSync('test/fixtures/test_cert.pfx'),
  passphrase: 'sample'
};

https.createServer(options, (req, res) => {
  res.writeHead(200);
  res.end('hello world\n');
}).listen(8000);
```

(Example from Node.js docs: [Https Example](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/https.html#https_https_createserver_options_requestlistener))

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do with all those files is to open them with Nodepad, and try to figure the `key` and `cert` as follows:

**Private Key (key option):**

Should have the string: *`-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`*

**Public Key (cert option):**

Should have the string *`-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----`*

**Note:**

If you find multiple `public keys`, i would go with `domain.X509Cert.crt` or `domain.PKCS7Cert.crt`(PK stands for Public Key).

As for `domain.rootCert.crt`, install it on your system server (not expressjs server).

**PS: Extensions don't matter that much**

Comment: none of them were contains private key. they're just PKCS7, certificate, and certificate request.