# Should the k8s Cluster Certificate Authority be kept secret?

Tags: kubernetes, ca

I have an azure aks cluster and a local kubeconfig:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Config
clusters:
- name: my-cluster
  cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: LS0...0tCg==
    server: https://api-server:443
contexts:
- name: my-context
  context:
    cluster: my-cluster
    namespace: samples
    user: my-context-user
current-context: my-context
users:
- name: my-context-user
  user:
    token: ey...jI
```

that is used for connecting to the cluster, listing pods etc.

From what I understand its important that the token in the kubeconfig is kept secret/private. But whats about the `certificate-authority-data`?

Since its just used to verify the the API server certificate I guess it has the same status as a public key and can be made public available at least for internal team members.

And is there and documentation that confirms this?

I did not find any info regarding that [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/configure-access-multiple-clusters/) or [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/).

Answer (score 3):

All clients (pods, normal users using kubeconfigfile, service accounts, component clients: kubelet to kube-apiserver etc.) are suing *ca.crt* in order to recognize self-signed certificates.

As we can see in the [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/#x509-client-certs)

> Client certificate authentication is enabled by passing the --client-ca-file=SOMEFILE option to API server. The referenced file must contain one or more certificate authorities to use to validate client certificates presented to the API server. If a client certificate is presented and verified, the common name of the subject is used as the user name for the request. As of Kubernetes 1.4, client certificates can also indicate a user's group memberships using the certificate's organization fields. To include multiple group memberships for a user, include multiple organization fields in the certificate.

In k8s cluster boostraped using kubeadm by default kube-apiserver is consigured with `--client-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt`.

As you can see in the [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/configure-access-multiple-clusters/#define-clusters-users-and-contexts) certificate-authority *ca.crt* should be be referenced in any config file for all clients which are used to securely connect with k8s cluster.

Sometimes you may want to use Base64-encoded data embedded here instead of separate certificate files; in that case you need to add the suffix -data to the keys, for example, certificate-authority-data, client-certificate-data, client-key-data

By default this value is Base64-encoded and embedded in tho the KubeconfigFile.

When your workload is accessing the k8s API from within a [Pod](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/access-api-from-pod/#without-using-a-proxy)
You can find also information about

```
# Reference the internal certificate authority (CA)
CACERT=${SERVICEACCOUNT}/ca.crt
```

by default *ca.crt* is located in `/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt`

Why *ca.crt* is included in all kubeconfigFiles - as we can see in the [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/certificates/#distributing-self-signed-ca-certificate)

> A client node may refuse to recognize a self-signed CA certificate as valid. For a non-production deployment, or for a deployment that runs behind a company firewall, you can distribute a self-signed CA certificate to all clients and refresh the local list for valid certificates.

According to your last statement.

> Since its just used to verify the the API server certificate I guess it has the same status as a public key and can be made public available at least for internal team members

`certificate-authority-data` should be included in all kubeconfig files for all internal team members, while `client-key-data` or tokens should be kept secret between different clients.

Comment: Ok so basically the short answer to my question I asked is that the CA itself is not sensitive and does NOT need to be kept in a secret - although the convention is to have it stored in based64?

Comment: tl;dr is yes, you don't have (or even should not) keep `certificate-authority-data` secret.
base64 is not there to encrypt the data but to encode it, it's a different thing. There is a good answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4657416/difference-between-encoding-and-encryption) explaining the difference.

Answer (score 2):

No, `certificate-authority-data` does not have to be kept secret. It's a [PEM encoded certificate](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/config-api/kubeconfig.v1/). You can base64-decode it to see the value, which will look something like the below.

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
fwoeijfoweifoewifoweifowiefoweif
feohfqofpqqpjfpqjfqpjpjpjpjpjpj
and so on
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

It does not say "private", so it just contains the public key. You can also write it to a file and read it in via `openssl x509 -in <filename>.pem -noout -text` to verify. You should see "Subject Public Key Info" but no mention of a private key.

Considering the kube_config may contain a sensitive token, you should consider keeping it a secret anyways just to be on the safe side.

Additional references:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/41470307/6629672
- https://www.reddit.com/r/kubernetes/comments/zsinn1